# iOS app with Delphi XE7 and XCode 6.2 crashes

Tags: delphi, ios-simulator, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

In an attempt to solve another problem, I upgraded my XCode from 6.1.1 to 6.2.
Now I can no longer run any application from Delphi XE7 upd1 in the simulator - not even an empty app. Always get an error in Delphi when run from Delphi: `Unable to create process` or some times `Debugger Assertion Failure rproxy.cpp line 663`.

The app is deployed, but when I try to start it directly in the simulator with a click on the icon, it only shows the splashscreen shortly and then closes/crashes.

Problem is the same no matter if I choose to target `Simulator7.1` or `Simulator8.2` (always runs in Simulator 7.1 on the Mac anyway). Also the same both for `Debug` and `Release` mode. Choosing Device as target works fine with an iOS8.2 iPad!

How to solve this problem with the simulator?
(did anyone make it work with XCode 6.2?)

PS. I have also asked this question on the Embarcadero forum, but since it is down 80% of the time, there is no chance anyone can answer it.

Comment: You can also try asking on http://community.embarcadero.com/ Some of Embarcadero employees are responding there

Comment: I have given up trying to use the iOS simulator with XE7 as I never got it to work. In fact, I have given up on Embarcadero and have bought a licence for Xamarin which has none of these stupid issues.  It just works...

Comment: And with Xamarin you get a true native application, on all platforms

Comment: @Brendan: Interesting if it really works - then I just need to convert 500k lines of code to C# :-)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: Thank you. I did not know about that page. Hopefully it is more stable than forums.embarcadero.com